# facing Unrecognized VM option 'UseSplitVerifier' for maven rest assured project

Tags: java, maven, jvm, frameworks, rest-assured

I am getting below error while trying to run any test case a run as testng for a maven rest assured project
Unrecognized VM option 'UseSplitVerifier'

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit,

please help me in resolving the issue

[image: Error]
[image]

Comment: What version of Maven compiler plug-in are you using? That option hasn’t been supported since Java 8…

Comment: <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.19.1</version>